# Read iframe content using Webbrowser C#

Tags: c#, iframe, browser, cross-domain, innertext

I know that I can access all iframes using the following properties of webbrowser:
string html = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].WindowFrameElement.InnerText;

But I'm struggling with cross-domain restriction.. 
My document url is like www.subdomain1.sport.com/...
And iframes url is like www.subdimain2.sport.com/...

How to access iframes content and put some text into input tag there?

Answer (score 2):

I think you must refer the following URL to get the content of IFrame which exists on cross domain.

http://codecentrix.blogspot.com/2008/02/when-ihtmlwindow2document-throws.html